# Adjectives next to a noun, separated by a comma

Tags: grammar, adjectives, commas, poetry

Can we add the adjectives of a noun next to it separated by a comma as below in poetry and in general?

> eg 1: Her hair, long and shiny, blowing in the wind {..}  
> eg 2: Your girl, her hair long and shiny, resemble a {...}

Comment: Note that the two examples aren't parallel.  The first is all subject (her hair), while the second contains a verb (resemble (which should be "resembleS".).

Comment: In poetry you can do whatever you want, so let's stick to "in general". Everything there is correct in general except for "resemble", as Ray already noted.